# Smartphone conflicting with LAN?

Tags: networking, routing

Recently, I've been having sporadic problems with internet connection on some computers. 
It turns out that an IPhone, when connected to the wlan, was causing this. These computers with Internet problems were somehow viewing this device as the gateway, and losing connection to the real gateway.

The smartphone's IP is assigned with DHCP and is valid, the device has hotspot turned off. What might be causing this?

**Edit with more details:**
My gateway is a router firewall server, IP 192.168.1.5.
I've been having every other morning this problem where some PCs start losing connection to the internet. Generally restarting my router solved the problem for the day, but it was happening so often that I had to diagnose this.

ARPing one of the disconnected machines you can see the MAC address for the gateway IP is different from the real gateway. It turns out it is one of the MAC addresses from one of the smartphones (BYOD :)) from here, even though it is given a specific correct IP by DHCP.  Connecting the IPhone to WLAN makes the disconnecting trend start, and removing it solves the issue instantly. WLAN is not separated from LAN.

Comment: BYOD strikes again.

Comment: Do you have any basis for your gateway hypothesis? Although an interesting question, an issue like this needs some good old fashioned low level diagnostics such as a packet trace.

Comment: @TomO'Connor BYOD on your corporate WLAN strikes again ;)

Comment: More detail, we need MUCH more detail

Comment: Edited with more details :)

Comment: I think Dan is right here, you might want to plug a computer into tthis router/firewall device and run Net Mon on it for a while see what kind of information is being dished out by the iPhone, generally that is a pretty harmless thing to have on the network so I'd suggest its possibly some kind of app thats been installed on the actual iPhone which is doing something could be acting as a proxy or sending proxy information to the other workstations on the network if that is at all possible.